# The "something<sup>somthing</sup>" is appearing as a plane text and not working as it to perform

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, griddle

I am having an issue that I am using the griddle.js and handsontable in my react application and I have to display a value with sup tag. But the output is the plane text with `//something<sup>somthing</sup>` but instead it should show like [sup tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup)

I mean the html tags are considered as plane text.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Sorry, I am beginner in Ractjs

```
const base_price = 100;
extProps.results = 'something' + base_price.sup();  //something + <sup>100</sup> 

   <Griddle
    ref="griddle"
    resultsPerPage={resultsPerPage}
    table_value = { extProps.results}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render html elements

```
const base_price = 100;
extProps.results = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "something <sup>100</sup>" }} />;

   <Griddle
    ref="griddle"
    resultsPerPage={resultsPerPage}
    table_value = { extProps.results}
  />
```

Comment: Thank you for the ans. 
Further, I am getting this error, if you could help again :)

**TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)**

Comment: Where do you get that error? can you share that code

Comment: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:6103), <anonymous>:4:26)
    at stateTransformer (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:5857), <anonymous>:103:51)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:9445), <anonymous>:113:30)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:8827), <anonymous>:22:18)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:9451), <anonymous>:47:20)
    at dispatch (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:9469), <anonymous>:45:18)
    at handleFulfill (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:9451), <anonymous>:138:11)

Comment: Are you doing JSON.stringify() anywhere in your code?

Comment: No I am asking are you doing JSON.stringify() anywhere in your code?

Comment: Warning: Exception thrown by hook while handling onSetChildren: Invariant Violation: Expected onMountComponent() to fire for the child before its parent includes it in onSetChildren().
Invariant Violation: Expected onMountComponent() to fire for the child before its parent includes it in onSetChildren().

Comment: This is another waring.

Comment: The problem is Griddle only except the string input while we are sending a non string input.

Comment: Sorry I can't help because I don't no anything about Griddle. I helped to fix your original issue because I have knowledge about that. If you need solution for Griddle then post as a separate question and tag griddle library so that people who knows about it will help you